# not supported; requires @DynamoDBTyped or @DynamoDBTypeConverted

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

Model Class:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName="PageState")
public class PageState {
    private String state;
    private String[] columns;
    
    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName="state")
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="columns")
    public String[] getColumns() {
        return columns;
    }

    public void setColumns(String[] columns) {
        this.columns = columns;
    }
}
```

Code for save PageState item

```
AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder
        .standard().withEndpointConfiguration(
                new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:8000", "eu-west-2")).build();
        
public PageState addPageState() {
    PageState metaData=new PageState();
    metaData.setState("NewPage1");
    String[] defaultColumns={ "AAA", "BBB", "CCC"};
    metaData.setColumns(defaultColumns);
    DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);
    mapper.save(metaData);

    return null;
}
```

Created table

```
var params = {
TableName: 'PageState',
KeySchema: [ 
    { 
        AttributeName: 'state',
        KeyType: 'HASH',
    },
],
AttributeDefinitions: [ 
    {
        AttributeName: 'state',
        AttributeType: 'S', 
    },
],
ProvisionedThroughput: { 
    ReadCapacityUnits: 5, 
    WriteCapacityUnits: 5, 
},
};

dynamodb.createTable(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) ppJson(err); // an error occurred
    else ppJson(data); // successful response

});
```

Getting the error on save the PageState object ;
**not supported; requires @DynamoDBTyped or @DynamoDBTypeConverted**

Comment: Can you post the actual error you are facing?